# Android remove the videoview pop up message

Tags: android, popup, android-videoview

I'd like to remove the popup message 'Sorry this video cannot be played' from the videoview in my app. I dont want my app to display any error messages.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set `ErrorListener` to your `VideoView` and `return true` from there and now no error will be shown.

**i.e:**

```
yourVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
  public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
     return true;
  }
});
```

Comment: now which code you want. I have shared the code clearly. Now replace yourVideoView with your w.