# "Activity has leaked window... that was originally added." caused by video that failed to load

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-2.3

I'm writing an android application that has an intro video that is an mp4 file that plays first. and the user can touch the screen to skip it.

when I try to run my application on an android emulator i get an "activity has leaked window.. that was originally added" exception. there is a big post about it on stackoverflow that says that if my something is trying to start up a dialog after the finish. to maybe in my case the player is trying to start up a dialog that says that the player doesn't support my video format.

ok.. so I just want the video to be skipped. without it throwing an errors and exceptions.

this is my Intro Activity:

```
package com.tuxin.findasmile;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
//import android.view.Menu; 
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class IntroActivity extends Activity {

private VideoView video;
private boolean isMenuStarted=false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

    video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    video.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
            Intent menu = new Intent(IntroActivity.this,MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(menu);
            finish();
            return false;
        }
    });
    video.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if (!isMenuStarted) { 
                isMenuStarted=true;
            Intent menu = new  Intent(IntroActivity.this,MenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(menu);
            finish();
            }

        }
    });
    Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.seaofbuttons);
    video.setVideoURI(videoUri);
    video.start();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (video.isPlaying()) {
        video.stopPlayback();
    }
    if (!isMenuStarted) {
    isMenuStarted=true;
    Intent menu = new Intent(IntroActivity.this,MenuActivity.class);
    startActivity(menu);
    finish();
    }
    return false;

}


}
```

i know that emulators do not support videos. but i want to support cases where phones do not suport this video format. i don't want an exception to be thrown.

```
04-01 16:32:38.675: E/WindowManager(533): Activity com.tuxin.findasmile.IntroActivity has     leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4052b9b0 that was originally added here
04-01 16:32:38.675: E/WindowManager(533): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.tuxin.findasmile.IntroActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4052b9b0 that was originally added here
04-01 16:32:38.675: E/WindowManager(533):   at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
04-01 16:32:38.675: E/WindowManager(533):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
04-01 16:32:38.675: E/WindowManager(533):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
04-01 16:32:38.675: E/WindowManager(533):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
04-01 16:32:38.675: E/WindowManager(533):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
04-01 16:32:38.675: E/WindowManager(533):   at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
04-01 16:32:38.675: E/WindowManager(533):   at android.widget.VideoView$4.onError(VideoView.java:386)
04-01 16:32:38.675: E/WindowManager(533):   at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:1341)
04-01 16:32:38.675: E/WindowManager(533):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-01 16:32:38.675: E/WindowManager(533):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-01 16:32:38.675: E/WindowManager(533):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-01 16:32:38.675: E/WindowManager(533):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-01 16:32:38.675: E/WindowManager(533):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-01 16:32:38.675: E/WindowManager(533):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-01 16:32:38.675: E/WindowManager(533):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-01 16:32:38.675: E/WindowManager(533):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3):

as much as I thought the answer to this question would be complicated.
all I needed to do is to return true in the onError function.

the thing is that it tried to display a dialog with the error message that the video cannot be viewed. i didn't see it cause I already moved to the next activity so this dialog was leaked and i saw this exception.

changing the onError return from false to true will change that behaviour of the VideoView not to create a Dialog with a message and because of that nothing will be leaked.

[Android remove the videoview pop up message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309412/android-remove-the-videoview-pop-up-message)

Comment: Thank you! I was busy trying to figure out how my progress dialog was leaking, turns out it was the error handler. I was calling finish() from onError(), so also never saw the attempted error dialog.